# Using button to add fields with text and choice in WTForms in a form

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

I've been trying, for a couple of days, to use an add field button to dynamically load two types of form objects: a StringField and a SelectField in a form. I want to add the fields when they are needed.

My project is in flask-wtforms-python.

The relevant pieces of the project, with the last attempt:

forms.py:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, TextAreaField #PasswordField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class DataForm(FlaskForm):

 single_ = StringField('Field name: ', validators=[InputRequired()])
 method_ = SelectField(u'Method: ', choices=[('modifySurname','Another surname'),
                                               ('modifyName','Another name'),
                                               ('modifyBuName','Another business'),
                                               ('toShuffle','Shuffle'),
                                               ('randomSimilar','Random'),
                                               ('modifyDate','Another day'),
                                               ('modifyAddress','Another address'),
                                               ('replaceEmail','Random email')                                               
                                                ])
```

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from forms import DataForm
 
#create the object of Flask
app  = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static')
 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'what3v4R'
 
#creating our routes
@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
 
@app.route('/data' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def Login():
    form = DataForm()
 
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return 'Form Submitted Successfully'
 
    return render_template('data.html', form = form)
 
#run flask app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

data.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body style="background-color: #DCDCDC;">{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %} Home {% endblock %} {% block
    body %} 
<h3>Single fields </h3>
        <table id="tbSF">
        <tr>
        <p>{{form.single_.label}} {{form.single_(size=32)}} Example: employee.lastname </p></div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <p>{{form.method_.label}} {{form.method_(size=1)}}</p></div>
        </tr>
        <tr><div id="sfRow"></div></tr>
        </table>
        <div><a href="javascript:void(0)"; id="addSF"; title="Add field"><button class="addSF">Add field</button></a></div>
        <script>        
        $(function(){
                $('#addSF').on('click', function() {
                var countingS = 2; 
                var addSingle =  $("<textarea></textarea></br>") 
                    .attr("class", "form-control") 
                    .attr("single_" + countingS) 
                    .attr("method_" + countingS) 
                    .attr("rows", "3") 
                    $("#sfRow").append(addSingle); 
                    countingS++; 
                    });
        });
        </script>   
    </div>
{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
    <!-- CSS Bootstrap CDN Link -->
  </head>
  <body>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename = '/css/style.css')}}">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">         
     <div class="container" style="background-color: tomato;"> 
      <span>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('index')}}">FAQ</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{url_for('index')}}">Help</a>
     </span> 
     </div>
    </nav>
    {% block body %} {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the display and the expected behavior would be to have both fields added with their labels after the existing fields:

[image]

Comment: Your code does not really reflect the question you ask. In the code you append a textarea but in the question you state that you want to "clone both fields"? How does the text-area fit into this?

Comment: Upon second view, the question is not really clear at all. Which may suggest why there are no answers yet. I just noticed that you have trailing underscores in your form-fields, but in JS you add a counter-variable to this. This is confusing. What do you intend to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

I hope you know what you need and are at least a basic python coder.
Below a snippet - click all clickable please, if you pick something and get lost with css or something - drop a comment - knowing which part you need I can extract needed css.
I don't like js, there is no js.
First - black - regular html `form` with html validation - thanks to `pattern` and `type`
Second - blue - simple single example of `html+css` magic
Third - teal (turquoise) - well, check it out

```css
body{ text-align: center; }
*{ box-sizing: border-box; outline: none}
form{ border: 10px solid #aaa; margin: 5vh auto; padding: 20px}
#black{ border-color: #000; color: #000}
#black input:invalid{ background: #def}
#blue{ border-color: #15f; color: #15f;}
#teal{ border-color: teal; color: teal}
#gold{ border-color: gold; color: orange}
div{ margin: 2vh; padding: 2vw}
form, label, button, details, summary{ display: block;}
label, input, select, textarea{ margin: 10px}
form, input, select, textarea, button, details{ padding: 10px}
textarea{ vertical-align: middle}
button, summary{ width: 100px; margin: 2vh auto;}
summary{ color: inherit; }
[open]>summary{ display: none}
.duet[open]>summary{ display: block; width: auto; font-weight: bold}
```

```html
<form id="black"><b>pure html</b> form with validation
<label>first name<input name="firstname" placeholder="first name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}" required></label>
<label>last name<input name="lastname" placeholder="last name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{2,}" required></label>
<label>middle name<input name="middlename" placeholder="middle name if known" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,}"></label>
<label>email<input type="email" name="email"></label>
<label>position<select name="position" required>
    <option value="" disabled> . </option>
    <option value="emploee">employee</option>
    <option value="manager">manager</option>
    <option value="director">director</option>
</select></label>
<label>notes<textarea name="txt" placeholder="optionally drop a line"></textarea></label>
<input type="submit"></form>

<form id="blue">html form <b>css trick</b>
<label>first name<input name="firstname" placeholder="first name" required></label>
<label>last name<input name="lastname" placeholder="last name" required></label>
<label>position<select name="position" required><option value="" disabled> . </option><option value="emploee">employee</option><option value="manager">manager</option><option value="director">director</option></select></label>
<details><summary>additional information</summary><label>middle name<input name="middlename" placeholder="middle name if known"></label><label>notes<textarea name="txt" placeholder="optionally drop a line"></textarea></label>
</details><input type="submit"></form>

<form id="teal">html form <b>css goes wild</b>
<label>first name<input name="firstname" placeholder="first name" required></label><label>last name<input name="lastname" placeholder="last name" required></label>
<label>position<select name="position" required><option value="" disabled> . </option><option value="emploee">employee</option><option value="manager">manager</option><option value="director">director</option></select></label>
<details><summary>additional information</summary><label>middle name<input name="middlename" placeholder="middle name if known"></label><label>notes<textarea name="txt" placeholder="optionally drop a line"></textarea></label>
<details class="duet"><summary>more additional information</summary><b>this one stays visible and clickable</b><label>male<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male"></label><label>female<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female"></label><label>other<input type="radio" name="sex" value="other"></label><label>something<input name="some1" placeholder="whatever needed 1"></label><label>a<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="a"></label><label>b<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="b"></label><label>c<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="c"></label>
<details><summary>another additional information</summary><label>something<input name="some2" placeholder="whatever needed 2"></label><label>notes<textarea placeholder="optionally drop a line"></textarea></label><details><summary>last time additional information</summary><label>something<input name="some3" placeholder="whatever needed 3"></label><label>notes<textarea placeholder="optionally drop a line"></textarea></label>
<details><summary>final addition</summary><fieldset><legend>fieldset of inputs</legend><label>something<input name="final" placeholder="final 1"></label><label>something<input name="final" placeholder="final 2"></label><label>something<input name="final" placeholder="final 3"></label><label>something<input name="final" placeholder="final 4"></label><label>notes<textarea name="final" placeholder="optionally drop a final line"></textarea></label></fieldset></details></details></details></details></details><input type="submit">
</form>
```